# I haven't gotten my Strunk & White badge

Tags: support, badges

I have done 80 post edits, but the Strunk & White badge isn't showing up in my profile.

[image]

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some badges are not triggered instantly. You have to wait a little. Sometimes even 1 day. 
I see that at the time I'm writing this you already have the badge.

Comment: Yes it's Add to my list